# Rails で今いるページの <title> の中身を取得する方法

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Facebook や Twitter のよくあるシェアボタンを作成しています。

[ここ](http://qiita.com/AkiraAlex/items/f224f8ee55a50ffe1a3f)などを参考にすると
Twitter のシェアボタンを実装する場合は

```html
<a class="twitter btn" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=[共有したいURL]&text=[任意のテキスト]&via=[ツイート内に含まれるユーザー名]&related=[関連アカウント]">tweetする</a>
```

と記載されているので、これを erb で記述しようとしているのですが

```erb
<%= link_to "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=#{ request.url }&text=#{ ここの [任意のテキスト] 部分に今いるページの <title> タグの中身を入れたい }&via=foobar" %>
```

といった感じで、共有したい URL の取得方法は分かったのですが
タグの中身の取得方法が分かりません…。

他にもっと効率的な手法などあれば、ご教示いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provideヘルパーを使ってはどうでしょうか？

まず、ページのタイトルを provideとyieldを使って表示するようにします。

views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= yield :title %></title>
  ...
</head>
<body>

  <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

views/static_pages/home.html.erb

```
<% provide :title, "ホーム" %>

<h1><%= yield :title %></h1>
<p>かくかく、しかじか</p>
```

このようにすると、`<%= yield :title %>`を使うことでtitleを取得できます。

```
<a class="twitter btn" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<%= request.url %>&text=<%= yield :title >&via=foobar>tweetする</a>

<%= link_to "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=#{ request.url }&text=#{ yield :title }&via=foobar" %>
```